# Secure Sqlite Database

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have made distribution profile from Apple Enterprise Account . I want to restrict the client from accessing to database . (using Xcode Organizer). What should I do ?

Comment: You can use [sqlcipher](http://www.zetetic.net/software/sqlcipher).

Comment: It's not clear exactly what your requirement is, but SqlCipher is the most heavily used encrypted DB on iOS.  Unfortunately, it's not quite "turnkey".

Comment: Do u have a demo project on sqlcipher + fmdb

Comment: I have a proprietary project with SqlCipher and FMDB.  This is not something where you can just cut-and-paste from an example.

Comment: i have tried sqlcipher but when building code it shows error on  libcrypto.a: No such file or directory, libssl.a: No such file or directory